# Do Git Sub-modules have to be in a Sub-directory?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm working on a project in a repository that uses sub-modules that contain sub-modules. I have noticed that some of the sub-modules depend on sub-modules that are already included by a different sub-module, and I'd like to clean up the repository some.

The most obvious solution to me is to move the actual sub-module repositories up to the root of my git directory (so their directories are in the same location as Project A's directory), and have use symlinks (or something else) inside each directory so that code isn't being repeated inside the main repository.

Is this possible?

To "draw" it out, I have (where the arrows point to sub-module dependencies)

```
~/A
  |->~/A/B
  |->~/A/C
         |->~/A/C/B
```

and I'd like to modify it so that I have:

```
~/A--|
     |___
~/B<-|<-|-|
~/C<----| |
  |_______|
```

This way, I won't have the code from B (which is relied on by many of my projects) duplicated every time a repository depends on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do.  That is, for a Git repository *R* to *be* a superproject with a submodule *S*, the submodule must appear as some path `path/to/submodule` within the superproject's work-tree.  The `path/to/` part can be empty, but the `submodule` part cannot.

The reason for this is:

- The fact that superproject *R* *has some submodule* *S* is recorded in `.gitmodules` files in *R*, and then in *R*'s `.git/config` file.  In particular, the URL that *R*'s `git submodule init` should use is in some `.gitmodules` file (which appears in multiple commits).  The path for that submodule is some nonempty path *P*, and both *P* and the URL get copied to `.git/config`.

  Once these are in the `.git/config` file, you can change them in the `.git/config` file.  Git will use those instead of the values in the `.gitmodules` files.  It's a good idea to keep committing the correct path and URL into `.gitmodules` because a *future* `git clone R` will very likely use the branch tip's `.gitmodules` file to populate that future clone's `.git/config` file.  (It's up to whoever runs `git clone` to make sure they populate the file correctly.  Using the selected tip commit's `.gitmodules` file is the default way to populate it.)
- More importantly, however, there is, at all times, *one specific commit* that the submodule should use.  That is, the superproject will run `cd path/to/submodule` (`cd P`) and then issue the command: `git checkout hash`.  That puts *S* on a detached HEAD at the given hash.  This action is done when you run `git submodule update`.<sup>1</sup>  The one specific commit is recorded as a *gitlink* in each commit in *R*.  That gitlink lives in the index—from which new commits are made—as an entry with path *P*.  The index can only hold paths of files that do, or at least can, live within the work-tree of repository *R*.

So for *R* to control *S*, Git will insist that *S* reside in a sub-directory of *R*.

If you don't need *R* to control *S*—if you want to just `git clone` several repositories yourself, and not have commits in *R* store gitlink entries that hold hash IDs taken (without *S*'s knowledge or consent) from *S*—then you can abandon the idea of using submodules at all, and get the layout you'd like.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can change the arguments passed to this `git checkout` via various flags and other actions and options, but the normal case is this sort of detached HEAD, *even if you specify a branch name* for *S* in your `.gitmodules` file and/or your `.git/config`.